# Creating large arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array in Swift that has 1000+ strings inside it. I am getting an error that looks like this:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Is there a place I can store a lot of strings in a way that won't break xcode, and if there is, how do I put them in and get the strings from it?

Comment: Segmentation fault 11 is very misleading. Are you 100% it is due to the size? I've had some seriously weird stuff resulting in sf 11.

Comment: Please post the code you think it's the cause of this error message. 1000+ strings - even when very large strings - most likely are not the reason for this problem.

Comment: I have a very small app. It has one extra swift file with the massive list, and all I do in the code is read a random item from the list. It was working perfectly a minute ago and then I added some more items and it started giving me an error. I have checked each line and there is nothing wrong with the syntax.

Comment: It's likely that you're trying to access an invalid index. Are you sure that the random number you're generating is an integer within the bounds of the array?

Comment: That is a compiler limitation that has been observed before. Loading the array from a resource file is the solution.

Comment: My tip is go back line by line until you work out which line actually causes the issue (using version control, step back in revisions). This is unlikely due to the size. I did a similar exercise not too long ago and my problem was a bug in Xcode. I moved two lines of code out to it's own function and everything worked.

Comment: How would I do that Martin R? I don't know how to open files, read lines and add them to arrays.

Comment: "I don't know how to open files, read lines and add them to arrays" Then you need to learn to do that. Don't freeze like a deer in the headlights. Learn.

Comment: My tip is: use NSArray or NSMutableArray instead of swift arrays(they're really slower).